# How to use templates with angular 1.x and webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Im trying to use webpack with my angular app but whenever I try loading in the html to the template I get errors. This is the one I'm currently getting:

> Module parse failed: C:\Users\Fabian\Dropbox\FixMyCity\FixMyCity\src\FixMyCity.Web\App\settings\settings.html Unexpected token (1:0)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Which makes me think that I don't have the right loader for html, but i've tried it with both `raw-loader` and `html-load` and neither of them have worked for me.

**Here is my current `webpack.config.js`**

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './App/app.js',
    output: {
        filename: './wwwroot/app-bundle.js'
    },
    loaders: [

            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
    ]
};
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['auth0', 'angular-storage', 'angular-jwt', 'ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', 'authProvider', 'jwtInterceptorProvider', '$httpProvider', configFunction])


function configFunction($routeProvider, authProvider, jwtInterceptorProvider, $httpProvider) {
    // Configure routes for your application
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
          template: require('./home/home.html'),
          requiresLogin: true
      })
}
```

Comment: did you insalled `html-loader` with `npm`?

Answer (score 1):

You must install html-loader from npm, after that you have to put in property loader the value 'html-loader'.

Like this:

```
module.exports = {
entry: './App/app.js',
output: {
    filename: './wwwroot/app-bundle.js'
},
loaders: [

        { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css' },
]};
```